# How to do sidemenu as a overlay in ionic?

Tags: css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm new to ionic framework. I need to follow ionic tags to do sidemenu overlay. Please help me.

The default style of sidemenu gives only drag style but i need the side menu as a overlay.

```
<ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="true">
  <ion-side-menu-content>
<ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">
  <ion-nav-back-button>
</ion-nav-back-button>

<ion-nav-buttons side="left">
  <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left">
 </button>
</ion-nav-buttons>

 </ion-nav-bar>
 <ion-nav-view name="menuContent"></ion-nav-view>
 </ion-side-menu-content>

  <ion-side-menu side="left">
  <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
  <h1 class="title">Left</h1>
  </ion-header-bar>
  <ion-content>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item menu-close ng-click="login()">
      Login
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/search">
      Search
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/browse">
      Browse
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/playlists">
      Playlists
    </ion-item>
   </ion-list>
   </ion-content>
   </ion-side-menu>
   </ion-side-menus>
```

Comment: The Simplest way i found for this topic [Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42803939/4627015)

Answer (score 0):

It's a toggleable side menu. If you want an overlay unfortunately you'll have to make your own.